# Pine Script series syntax / access

Tags: pine-script

who can help a newbie? don't understand following syntax I found in a Pine script:

```
long[1]+1
```

long[1] is the second last element of series "long", right? but what means long[1]+1 ???

Answer (score 0):

Its simple addition to the "long[1]" value and 1 , "long[1]" must int/float type otherwise you will get error.